# SQL query error: The multi-part identifier "sys.schemas" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the error

> The multi-part identifier `sys.schemas` could not be bound. The
>   multi-part identifier `sys.tables` could not be bound.

With the following code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Statement2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @FinalStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = sys.schemas 
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = sys.tables

SELECT
        @Statement = @Statement + 'SUM(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13) ,
        @Statement2 = @Statement2 + COLUMN_NAME + '*100 / OverallCount AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13) FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      RAISERROR('TABLE OR VIEW with schema "%s" and name "%s" does not exists or you do not have appropriate permissions.',16,1, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME)
ELSE
BEGIN
       SELECT @FinalStatement =
               'SELECT ' + LEFT(@Statement2, LEN(@Statement2) -2) + ' FROM (SELECT ' + LEFT(@Statement, LEN(@Statement) -2) +
               ', COUNT(*) AS OverallCount FROM ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME + ') SubQuery'

       EXEC(@FinalStatement)
END
```

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Error + code doesn't tell us much

Comment: Are you just failing to quote what should be *strings* when you assign values to `@TABLE_SCHEMA` and `@TABLE_NAME` at the top?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes possibly but I am a SQL novice so I'd appreciate if you could correct my code for me so I can see how I can turn them to strings?

Comment: @Justin, this is a query to find null or blank values and % completeness in values for all the tables in my database.

Comment: The first issue is you're looking for a `COLUMN_NAME` that is `NULL`. As far as I'm aware you can't create a column with no name. So when you say value you want the actual value or you want to find columns that have a `Default NULL`
Secondly, what do you mean by % completeness in values?

Comment: Ok, well I'm trying to find a way for a query to calculate either the percentage of NULL or blank values in each column for each table in my database (around 20 tables). OR conversely, find the number of fields that have a value in them (% completeness, not null or blank). I would like one query to bring back a table with a table name, column name, and a % completeness or % null/blank in them. Is this possible?

Comment: So the logic of what you want to achieve is: `FOR EACH` table you have in your database. Do a count on each column for `NULLS` VS `NOT NULL` and based on this work out the % completeness. 
This possible but its not a very good query to be running often. Could take a while to run if you're doing this on production and depending on how many rows you have too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for has similarities to what this person achieved here:

- recursively go through each table and find the total number of `NULL` values.

But do bear in mind that this can take a while depending on the size of your database.

```
<!-- language: lang-SQL -->

DECLARE @schemaName AS sysname;
DECLARE @tableName AS sysname;
DECLARE @columnName AS sysname;
DECLARE @schema_id AS int;
DECLARE @object_id AS int;
DECLARE @column_id AS int;
DECLARE @isNullable AS bit;
DECLARE @lastSchema_id AS int;
DECLARE @lastTable_id AS int;
DECLARE @recordCount AS bigint;
DECLARE @nullCnt AS bigint;
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @paramDefinition NVARCHAR(max);

if exists(select name from tempdb..sysobjects where name LIKE'#Columns%')
DROP TABLE #Columns;

CREATE TABLE #Columns (
    schema_id int,
    object_id int,
    column_id int,
    schemaName sysname,
    tableName sysname,
    columnName sysname,
    recordCnt bigint,
    nullCnt bigint,
    nullPct numeric(38,35) );

-- Set to the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id to NULL so that the first 
--  loop through the cursor the record count is generated.
SET @lastSchema_id = NULL;
SET @lastTable_id = NULL;

-- List of all the user schemas.tables.columns
--  in the database
DECLARE c_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT schemas.schema_id
     , all_objects.object_id
     , all_columns.column_id
     , schemas.name AS schemaName
     , all_objects.name AS tableName
     , all_columns.name AS columnName
     , all_columns.is_nullable
  FROM sys.schemas
 INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
    ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
   AND all_objects.type = 'U'
 INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
    ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id
 ORDER BY schemas.schema_id
     , all_objects.object_id
     , all_columns.column_id;

OPEN c_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
 INTO @schema_id
    , @object_id
    , @column_id
    , @schemaName
    , @tableName
    , @columnName
    , @isNullable;

-- Loop through the cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Get the record count for the table we are currently working on if this is
    --  the first time we are encountering the table.
    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @recordCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@recordCount bigint OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @recordCount = @recordCount OUTPUT;

    END

    -- If the column is NOT NULL, there is no reason to do a count
    --  Set the nullCnt and nullPct to 0
    IF ( @isNullable = 0 )
    BEGIN


        INSERT INTO #Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct )
        VALUES
             ( @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , 0
             , 0.0 );
    END
    -- If the column is NULL, count the number of NULL fields in the table.
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @nullCnt = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
                   N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N' IS NULL;';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@nullCnt bigint OUTPUT';

        PRINT @SQL;

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @nullCnt = @nullCnt OUTPUT;

        INSERT INTO #Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct )
        VALUES
             ( @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , @nullCnt
             -- USE NULLIF in case there are no recods in the table
             , ISNULL( @nullCnt * 1.0 / NULLIF( @recordCount, 0) * 100.0, 0 ) );

    END

    -- Set the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id so that on 
    --  the next loop, if it's the same table there is no 
    --  need to recount the columns for the table.
    SET @lastSchema_id = @schema_id;
    SET @lastTable_id = @object_id;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
     INTO @schema_id
        , @object_id
        , @column_id
        , @schemaName
        , @tableName
        , @columnName
        , @isNullable;

END;

CLOSE c_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE c_Cursor;

SELECT *
  FROM #Columns;
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3e097cad-f355-4f7e-b265-f7e6137670bf/challenge-how-to-count-nulls-for-each-column-in-every-table-in-vldb-etc?forum=transactsql

Comment: This looks great, thanks, will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

`sysname` is some character variant. You can't do

```
DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = sys.schemas
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = sys.tables
```

you need to use quotes as with `char`, `varchar`, etc.. Use

```
DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = 'sys.schemas'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = 'sys.tables'
```

to fix the error.

Edit:

And since you apparently want to use these values to filter on the schema name and table name separately (

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA
```

) you should only assign the right part to each variable:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = 'some_schema_name'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = 'some_table_name'
```

A schema with the **name** `sys.schemas` is unlikely to exist. As well as a table **named** `sys.tables` (I'm talking about just the name. Of course this is otherwise a qualified identifier including the schema.).

E.g.:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = 'sys'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = 'tables'
```

(But `sys.tables` doesn't seem to bee listed in `information_schema.columns`. But I guess your not after system but "regular" tables anyway.)

Comment: Ah, thank you, this makes more sense. Noted!